# Count all Jest test functions without running the tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to extend Jest so that I can very quickly be notified every time I run all my tests and they're all green (I've [done this for JUnit 5](https://schmonz.com/software/greencently/) and there's [a little FAQ](https://schmonz.com/software/greencently/faq/)).

In the Jest source code, so far I'm only seeing test *files* being passed around a bunch of places (I can get a list of those files with `jest --listTests`). But I haven't yet found where or how the *functions* in those files get enumerated. The only way I've figured out to get a test function count for the whole project is to run Jest over the whole project. For my use case, that may have already just happened and if I have to do it a second time then my code won't be saving anyone any time.

Ideally, Jest would present a public API to its test discovery mechanism. I'd ask it for the complete list of all test functions in the project, or even just the count of those functions, and it would respond quickly.

Alternatively I'd be happy being pointed at private API calls that I can stitch together to do this, with the understanding that when my code inevitably breaks I get to keep both pieces, or being pointed at a mostly copy-pastable bit of code that does test discovery exactly the same way Jest currently does it.

Where should I look in the Jest source code to find out, given a test file, how many test functions it contains?

Comment: This has a _lot_ of failure states. You don't just need to know how many tests ran last, you need to know exactly _which_, and what their content was. If one got removed and one added, the count's the same. If the content of a test changes, the count and even list is the same, but the result of running the suite might not be.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways for this algorithm to yield wrong results. This is mitigated by the expectation that tests get run unconditionally on push and by the typically small window during which the previous all-green is honored.